# "starts with" with an href-tag instead of id

Tags: jquery

In working with modals in the following manner:

```
$(document).on('click', "[href=\"#edit-my-modal\"]", function() { 
      ...
 }
```

Now i need to be able to do the same thing with dynamic ids which is added to the end of the current id, like this for example:

```
$(document).on('click', "[href=\"#edit-my-modal_1\"]", function() { 
          ...
     }
```

So i am trying to trigger this click-event using jQuery "starts with" in order to trigger the same event if the id starts with:`#edit-my-modal_`.

If it was an id instead of an href triggering the function i could have used:

```
[id^='edit-my-modal_']
```

But how can this be done using an href as in my code?
Help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `[href^='#edit-my-modal_']`?

Comment: why u are not doing this by class even that is too simple..even its not a good practice to write like this.Let me know if you want code with class i can provide you.

Comment: [href^='#edit-my-modal_'] seems to work :)
Thank you!
@SINGH Thank you for offering. I think I can manage from here. Thanks!

Comment: @Louis9898 i have added code snip you can check my answer and if it works please accept.

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector `[id*=\"edit-my-modal_\"]` then you can find all element contains `edit-my-modal_` + etc.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id*=\"edit-my-modal_\"]', function() { 
      console.log(this.id);
});

$(document).on('click', '[href*=\"edit-my-modal_\"]', function() { 
      console.log(this.href);
});
```

```css
a {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>With id</h2>
<a id="edit-my-modal_1">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_2">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_3">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_4">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_5">Click</a>
<h2>With href</h2>
<a href="#edit-my-modal_5">Click</a>
<a href="#edit-my-modal_4">Click</a>
<a href="#edit-my-modal_3">Click</a>
<a href="#edit-my-modal_2">Click</a>
<a href="#edit-my-modal_1">Click</a>
```

Comment: writing this is not a good practice bcz its a little complex same can be done with class.

Comment: @SINGH Right, OP can do this via `class` too. But it depends to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with class.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="edit-my-modal_1" class="modal">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_2" class="modal">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_3" class="modal">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_4" class="modal">Click</a>
<a id="edit-my-modal_5" class="modal">Click</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.modal', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  })
})
</script>
</body>
```

```html
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a id="edit-my-modal_1" class="modal">Click</a>
    <a id="edit-my-modal_2" class="modal">Click</a>
    <a id="edit-my-modal_3" class="modal">Click</a>
    <a id="edit-my-modal_4" class="modal">Click</a>
    <a id="edit-my-modal_5" class="modal">Click</a>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
      $(document).on('click', '.modal', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
      })
    })
    
  </script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```